# How to pass more than one parameter to url in django

Tags: python, html, django, href, url-parameters

HTML page has 2 button to process payment, I need to pass 2 parameters to url for a reason. Below is the method I tried but it's not working. Can someone help me here..??

```
<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id button.id %}"   id = "CashOnDelivery" class="btn btn-warning"> Cash on Delivery</a> 
<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id button.id %}"  id = "Card" class="btn btn-warning">Pay through Card</a>
```

**views.py**

```
def process_payment(request, order_id, button_id):
    if id == CashOnDelivery
     # directly take order
    return redirect (reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))

    else 
     # process the card payment then update transaction 
    return redirect (reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
 path('payment/<order_id>/<button_id>',views.process_payment, name='process-payment'),
]
```

Comment: Could you at least post the error message you are getting?

Comment: @errorinpersona Error Message: **Reverse for 'process-payment' with arguments '(88, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/payment/(?P<order_id>[^/]+)/(?P<button_id>[^/]+)$']**  It's taking the order_id but not the button_id.

Comment: No the button.id is just empty. You should check that.

Comment: @errorinpersona That's exactly my question...How?

Comment: The easiest way is prolly: {{ button.id }} somewhere in your template and check if it prints out something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your variable is not defined.

`<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id 'CashOnDelivery' %}"   id = "CashOnDelivery" class="btn btn-warning"> Cash on Delivery</a>`.

`<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id 'Card' %}"  id = "Card" class="btn btn-warning">Pay through Card</a>`.

Also there seems you are not checking right id.

````
def process_payment(request, order_id, button_id):
    if button_id == CashOnDelivery
     # directly take order
    return redirect (reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))

    else 
     # process the card payment then update transaction 
    return redirect (reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))```
````

Comment: Why?? **button_id** should be either 'CashOnDelivery' or 'Card' right? since the 2nd paramater which was sent to url matches with url pattern `path('payment/<order_id>/**<button_id>**` also I have used the same into views `def process_payment(request, order_id, **button_id**):`

Comment: have you defined `button.id` variable anywhere? How URL  know what does `button.id` means?

Comment: I was just missing out this part `<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id 'CashOnDelivery' %}"` didn't know a way to pass 2nd paramater to url. Now it's working fine. Thank you. One more change  `if button_id == "CashOnDelivery" ` --missed double quotes simple mistakes.

Comment: button_id in views I will be getting from -->urlpattern button_id into urlpattern I will be getting from this part -->`<a href="{% url 'process-payment' order.id 'CashOnDelivery' %}"`